# How to fix "_filePath.includes is not a function. ( In '_filePath.includes('&'), '_filePath.includes' is undefined)" in React Native?

Tags: firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image to Firebase Storage, however, ref.putfile() leads to the error in the tittle

I didn't find any appropriate resource related to this error

This is where I get image from user:

```
openPicker = () =>  {

    // More info on all the options is below in the API Reference... just some common use cases shown here
    const options = {
      title: 'Fotoğraf Seç',
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images',
      },
    };
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      }
      else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      }
      else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      }
      else {
        const source = { uri: response.uri}
        this.setState({
          imageMessageSrc: source
        });
        this.uploadImage();
      }
    });

  }
```

Then I try to uploadImage to firebase

```
 uploadImage = () => {
    console.log("Here");
    const filename = this.randIDGenerator// Generate unique name
    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(`${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/sentPictures/${filename}`)
      .putFile(this.state.imageMessageSrc)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Here1");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
```

When I delete putFile, error is gone, but obviously nothing happens to database.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Yes I have solved this problem. Check solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is related to the difference between filePath and fileUri. So, the solution is as below:

```
    openPicker = () => {
            const options = {
                title: 'Fotoğraf Seç',
                storageOptions: {
                    skipBackup: true,
                    path: 'images',
                    allowsEditing: true,
                },
            };

            ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
                console.log('Response = ', response);

                if (response.didCancel) {
                    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
                }
                else if (response.error) {
                    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
                }
                else if (response.customButton) {
                    console.log('User tapped custom button: ',response.customButton);

                }
                else {
                    var path = '';
                    if (Platform.OS == 'ios')
                        path = response.uri.toString();
                    else {
                        path = response.path.toString();
                    }
                    const image= {
                        image: response.uri.toString(),
                        path: path
                    };
                    this.uploadImage(image);
                }
            });
        }
     uploadImage = (image) => {
           firebase.storage().ref(uploadUrl).putFile(image.path);
}
```

I realized that *Firebase Storage putFile* function doesn't work with image uri, instead it should be supplied with filePath. I used uri of this image to directly show image on the screen even before upload.

Comment: Does this apply also if we're trying this from Android emulator? I'm having issue with Android only, regardless if I use response.uri or response.path..

Comment: @bra.Scene, I am doing tests on a real device only, so I don't know whether it works on emulator.